# Combo box not populating in flex in IE 8.0.7601

Tags: apache-flex, combobox

We have been facing an issue with displaying the list of States in a drop-down/combo-box in IE.We do have 1 REST web-service which reads the list of States string values from a Constant.java file and return to Flex command; which in turn is the data-provider for combo-box.
Flex code is as below; in callback() we are simply pushing the elements from response list into object.

```
private function loadStates():void
{
    model.stateCode=new Array();
    model.statesArr=new Array();
    var obj:Object=new Object();
    var objOne:Object=new Object();
    obj={label: "Select", tip: "Select the state"};
    objOne={label: "Select State", data: "Select State"};
    model.stateCode.push(obj);
    model.statesArr.push(objOne);
    for (var i:int=0; i < model.stateDetail.length; i++)
    {
        obj={"label": model.stateDetail[i].stateCode, "tip":                                                                        
            model.stateDetail[i].stateDecsription};
        objOne={"label": model.stateDetail[i].stateCode + '-' + 
            model.stateDetail[i].stateDecsription, "data":  
            model.stateDetail[i].stateCode};
        model.stateCode.push(obj);
        model.statesArr.push(objOne);
    }
 }
```

Comment: How you are passing data to combobox? are you using binding? and when you are calling webservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a bit of a simplistic answer, but since Array does not have a refresh option, I have sometimes noticed that it can be better to fully populate the Array first, and then apply it as the dataProvider to whatever list/comboBox you are working with. This sometimes has to be done each time the Array is updated.

Otherwise, maybe try using an ArrayCollection, and then the .refresh() after it has been 
populated

Brian

Comment: Thanks Brian.. I was able to fix this the way you suggested. However updating this with Thanks Note just now :)